# Page elements flying in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My purpose is to modify my page to load elements by "flying in". I found [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/km3TE/), and I should now make it to happen on page load, without clicking anything. So it triggers on page load.

```
$(function() {
    $("#add-sidebar-module").on("click", function() {
        $("<div />", {
            'class': "module",
            text: "I'm new here."
        }).prependTo("#sidebar");
    });

    $("#add-article").on("click", function() {
        $("<div />", {
            'class': "module",
            html: "<h1>Title</h1><p>text text text.</p>"
        }).prependTo("#main");
    });
});
```

I'm also afraid that there is some kind of issues in what comes to the page loading and the animation. Tips and tricks to make sure it's as smooth as possible would be welcome!

Comment: Have u added the css?

Comment: @Sweetz I already provided the link to JSFiddle, there is the CSS for this animation. This question was more about jQuery / JS based, on how to get this to load when the page loads up.

Comment: try triggering click event on page load

Comment: Add the animation class on page load (within the $(function() {});)

Comment: @speak Could you provide me a JSFiddle and post it as an answer so if that works I can close this and mark as answered! Thanks already!

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/km3TE/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PJN6r/

```
<div class="animate-on-load">
    This is animated
</div>


$('.animate-on-load').addClass('module');
```

As per your request.

I would not suggest triggering a click on page load. Just add the class on load.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/smckaysmalley/fly-in.js). It animates any element you want when the page loads, so that you don't have to click anything.

Here is a [demo](http://smckaysmalley.github.io/ski_survey/) of it.

To use this plugin, make sure you first include jQuery on any pages that use it, and include the JavaScript file as well.

Then wrap this tag around all elements you want to fly-in.

```
<div class="runway">
... fly-in elements go here ...
</div
```

Finally add either `fly-in-right` or `fly-in-left` class to the DOM element you wish to animate.

```
<img class="fly-in-left" src="..." />
```

And that should do it! When the element if visible on the page, it will animate a 'fly-in'!

Answer (score 1):

This is more smooth effect: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/km3TE/8/)

```
    .module {
    -webkit-animation: flyin 1s cubic-bezier(.62, -0.36, .4, 1.28);
    -moz-animation: flyin 1s cubic-bezier(.62, -0.36, .4, 1.28);
    -o-animation: flyin 1s cubic-bezier(.62, -0.36, .4, 1.28);
    -ms-animation: flyin 1s cubic-bezier(.62, -0.36, .4, 1.28);
    animation: flyin 1s cubic-bezier(.62, -0.36, .4, 1.28);
}
@-webkit-keyframes flyin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes flyin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes flyin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes flyin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flyin {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.main, .sidebar {
    padding: 1em;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
.module {
    border: 0.5em solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, looks a lot smoother than what it was!